# Why prettify mistakes `/*` as comment for "shell script"

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Specifically [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136486/41104). Apparently it's interpreting `/*` as the beginning of a comment which it isn't in any shell I known of (only JS, Java and some C-like language to my limited knowledge do this). I forced bash syntax highlighting with the `<!-- language -->` stanza and the results changed, so it was fault of the shell-script tag. I don't know how much SE modified prettify library to <s>start shouting and flipping tables</s> give an accurate diagnostic of where the bug is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The syntax highligher for this js script seems to have a bug for the code after the \*/](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/the-syntax-highligher-for-this-js-script-seems-to-have-a-bug-for-the-code-after)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's failing on that question because it's tagged with both [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script). [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) is associated with the "bsh" language, which I guess is a bash-specific highlighting. [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) is associated with generic shell script highlighting. Since the question has two languages defined, prettify doesn't know which it should use and falls back on just doing generic highlighting, which doesn't work great. Specifying the language manually is probably the right fix.

Comment: Can you modify the language for shell-script to bash? Since that's almost all the shell script question posted in the site written with, we may just tell the system so.

Comment: From what I can tell, bsh, csh, and sh are all [highlighted the same](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js#728), so I changed the bash tag to use sh highlighting. Seems to work