# Is there something wrong with tags determining the language for syntax highlighting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Is it just me, or has the language detection from tags for syntax highlighting been broken lately? I seem to have noticed a couple of times that scripts containing `/*` were highlighted as if it that started a comment, like in C, even though the questions had proper-looking shell-related tags.

For example, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499128/170373) to a question tagged both [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) looks like this to me:

> [image]

Adding `<!-- language: bash -->` or `<!-- language: shell -->` manually fixes it, but that doesn't scale too well..

Comment: That's weird. I just double checked and the `sh` tag is correctly set to highlight with "lang-sh". Maybe it's the lang-sh that's broken. I will try changing the default for `sh` to `lang-bash` and see if that helps.

Comment: Apparently, we've been here before, this question from 4.5 years had the exact same issue: [Why prettify mistakes `/*` as comment for “shell script”](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2948/170373) (just noticed that from the Related questions list)

Answer (score 9):

The [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) was set to highlight using `lang-sh`. I just changed that so it uses `lang-bsh` instead and that seems to have fixed the issue. I don't know if that's because `lang-sh` was broken or because `lang-sh` actually refers to some other language and not `sh`, but it seems to be OK now:

[image: screenshot of the same answer but now with correct highlighting]

If anyone notices issues or objects to having [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) default to bash-style syntax highlighting, please let me or another mod know, preferably by opening a meta thread.

Comment: The two tags had different format options specified: lang-sh and lang-bsh. The code formatting script considers them the same, but the SE logic which applies them does not - so it reverted to the default formatter. The default formatter thinks C-style comments are super cool and everyone uses them all the time. By changing the tags to use the same option, you resolved the ambiguity - changing them both to lang-sh would also have worked.

Comment: @Shog9 oooh! Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Shog9, haa, interesting, thanks!

Comment: @terdon, there's still the [tag:shell] tag that has `lang-sh`, so if I get this right, the conflict can arise again if that's used with e.g. [tag:bash]. If `lang-sh` and `lang-bsh` are the same with the actual formatting, maybe all three should be changed to `lang-sh` (or `lang-bsh`, but I think `sh` is clearer). The [tag:zsh], [tag:ksh] etc. tags don't seem to have languages set, so they shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks, I just changed that to `lang-bsh` as well. I agree that `lang-sh` would make more sense but since many were already set to `bsh`, it was easier to change the rest as well.